# Sass conditional ampersand

Tags: css, sass

I have some sass that looks like this

```
.activities {
  border: 1px solid green;

  .activity {
    background-color: red;

    &:first-child {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  }  
}
```

I want `.activity` element that is a first child to be yellow only when the parent element with `.activities` class does not also have the class `.events`.

In the example below, the first `.activity` element should have `background-color: red`

```
<div class="activities events">
  <div class="activity">one</div>
  <div class="activity">two</div>
  <div class="activity">three</div>
</div>
```

Is there a DRY way to negate this first-child style when the element with `.activities` also has `.events`?

or is this the simplest way:

```
.events .activity:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think the bottom way is the simplest/driest. You could also use the `:not` selector but that would be more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:not` selector to apply the yellow background when the activities element doesn't have the events class.

```
.activities {
    border: 1px solid green;

    .activity {
        background-color: red;
    }

    &:not(.events) {
        .activity:first-child {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    }  
}
```

This method helps to cut down on duplication. If you suddenly decide activity should be blue rather than red you only have to change it in one place, not two.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 1):

I was bored and wanted to see if I could keep all the `activity` styles within just one `activity` child and came up with this - though I wouldn't recommend to use this over Nathan's answer, because this really is a pointless over-the-top solution:

```
.activities {
  border: 1px solid green;

  .activity {
    background-color: red;

    &:first-child {
      @at-root #{selector-replace(&, '.activities', '.activities:not(.events)')} {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And if you didn't want to repeat the 'activities' class, you could cache it as a variable:

```
.activities {
  $this: &;

  border: 1px solid green;

  .activity {
    background-color: red;

    &:first-child {
      @at-root #{selector-replace(&, $this, '#{$this}:not(.events)')} {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Has Sass gone too far?